# calling intents created in dialogFlow console

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

Since I am new to dialogFlow coding, i have  few questions related to intents created in console DialogFlow.

1)      If I create one intent “intent1” in dialogFlow console, is it possible to call this intent in firebase functions ?If yes, how to do this?

2)      How to make the user to select options instead of typing? What I have to use for this?

3)      How to configure the intents to be called whenever user type number?

4)      What is the purpose of entity, events and action & parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am somewhat new to Actions on Google programming still, but here is my understanding.

Dialogflow allows you to define intents. You can then define code to implement those intents. The console provides an inline JavaScript editor to Google Cloud Functions. You can go to the Google cloud functions console and see the code there. Or you can flip it over to "web fulfillment" if you want to deploy more complicated code (e.g. split the JavaScript over several files - the built in editor only works with a single index.js file).

So dialogflow takes the human input (a phrase they say), looks down the training set of phrases for different intents, and picks the one it thinks is correct. It then invokes the fulfillment code of that intent (where the code is stored in firebase). So when you ask "is it possible to call this intent in firebase functions" that feels kinda backwards. Intents are the glue between the user saying something and calling a firebase function (via HTTP). Intents are not in themselves code that can be called.

If you want the user to select options, you can either create an entity with the option names (like "one", "two", "three" etc), or create intents for each option name. There would be a "one" intent, triggered when the user says "one". It is up to your application code to know where the user is in the menu browsing structure to know what "one" means. (You can also use Suggestions on devices with screens to show them options they have to tap on.) Ideally you would allow the user to say phrases or numbers, to give more flexibility.

So your third question (how to configure intents to be called whenever the user types a number), your application may do something like start with the default "welcome" intent (the starting point). You would verbally say the menu choices "say one for homewares, two for clothing, three for shoes, ...". You then remember the user's position in the menu. You then wire up "one" as an intent, and in the Cloud Function it would check which menu the user was up to, so would know "just after the welcome intent, 'one' means homewares". The app may then ask a second question like "say one for furniture, two for vases, three for disco balls, ...". If they say 'one' again, it would go to the same intent, but your app would have saved away a variable keeping track of where the user is in the menu tree.

Entities allow you to define a vocabulary of terms. E.g. "I want to buy a ${color} ${thing}". You can define a color entity with values "red", "green", "blue" etc. You can define a second thing entity of "dress", "hat", "shoes" etc. The intent training phrase might be "I want to buy a red dress". Dialogflow can be told "red" in that training sentence is a "color" entity, and "dress" is a "thing" entity. These values are then passed as parameters to the web service backing the implementation - that is, your "buy" intent would get a "color" and "thing" parameter.

Events are system generated triggers instead of user input triggers. For example the "welcome" intent to start off your app is a system generate event. Another event is used when an app moves from one device to another. There are other system events if you ask for permission to start using push notifications. It is a way to get your code run if something happens (not just when a user says something).

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can call one intent directly via Events, or you can send a request via the API and allow the intent to be matched automatically by the engine. Follow the instructions on [the SDK documentation here](https://dialogflow.com/docs/sdks#detect_intent_and_agent_apis). But essentially what you do is:

```
const dialogflow = require('dialogflow');
const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient();
// Define session path
const sessionPath = sessionClient.sessionPath(projectId, sessionId);

const r_text = "What's the weather like in Rio de Janeiro?"

// The text query request.
const request = {
  "session": sessionPath,
  "queryParams": {
    "payload": payload
  },
  "queryInput": {
    "text": {
      "text": r_text,
      "languageCode": languageCode,
    },
  },
};

return sessionClient
.detectIntent(request)
.then(responses => {
  console.log('Detected intent');
  const result = responses[0].queryResult;
  ...do stuff with responses...
  return Promise.resolve('Resolved intent');
})
if (result.intent) {
  console.log(`  Intent: ${result.intent.displayName}`);
  return Promise.resolve('Resolved intent');
} else {
  console.log(`  No intent matched.`);
  return Promise.resolve('Not resolved intent');
}
```

Also, when defining your payload, be aware of a little annoying bug (which has costed me a couple of days) and convert your JSON into the structure that the API expect to receive:

```
const payload = structjson.jsonToStructProto({
  "user": userId,
  "location": r_location,
  "timestamp": r_timestamp,
  "sender": r_sender
})
```

You can find the [structjson library](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow/blob/master/samples/structjson.js) on Google's repo.